# What exactly is the difference between "WSO2 API Manager" and "WSO2 Data Analytics Server" and "WSO2 Application Server"?

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-as, wso2-identity-server

I am absolutly new in **WSO2** and I have the following doubts.

I am following this official training video course: http://wso2.com/training/apim-self-paced?video=2#request_training_enroll

that contains a labkit PDF (you can obtain it clicking on the *Download Lab kit** button.

So at the beginning of this PDF file it is explained also as install and start these 3 **WSO2** component:

1) **WSO2 API Manager**: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Installing+on+Windows

2) **WSO2 Data Analytics Server**: https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Installing+on+Windows

3) **WSO2 Application Server**: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Installing+on+Windows

I have correctly installed these 3 software and I can start these web application going into the **/bin/** and executiong this bat file:

```
wso2server.bat --run
```

Then I access to the web interface of these softwares opening in the browser this URL:

```
https://localhost:9443/carbon/
```

My main doubt is that opening this URL for each of these 3 software I am obtaining always the same web interface. Also if I log in as admin credential I am obtaining the same dashboard.

So what exactly is the difference between these 3 software? For wich pourpose I have to use one instead another?

2) All run on the **9443** port so I can't run these software at the same time. Maybe have I to change the port to do it?

Comment: You can change the Port offset on each of these in repository/conf/carbon.xml. P.S. Otherwise, I would advise you to read the information about them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the port offset of each tool in:

```
[WSO2_TOOL]\repository\conf\carbon.xml
```

In section:

```
<Ports>

    <!-- Ports offset. This entry will set the value of the ports defined below to
     the define value + Offset.
     e.g. Offset=2 and HTTPS port=9443 will set the effective HTTPS port to 9445
     -->
    <Offset>0</Offset>
```

For example:

For API Manager = 0

URL: https://localhost:9443/carbon/

Used for: API developement

---

For DAS = 1

URL: https://localhost:9444/carbon/

Used for: Monitoring other tools integrated with it and for IoT

---

For AS = 2

URL: https://localhost:9445/carbon/

Used for: deploy web services in axis2 and jax-ws, and deploy webapp.